# How to use Microsoft (not Organizational) account with Add-AzureAccount?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I'm trying to use the `Add-AzureAccount` command that's part of the Azure PowerShell tools (August 2014, v0.8.6), and although various examples on the web lead me to expect that it will let me use either an organizational account or a Microsoft Account to log in, in practice, it seems to be requiring an organizational account.

When I execute the command, it opens a hosted browser window as expected, but the prompt says `Sign in with your organizational account` followed by a username and password. There seems to be no way to tell it that no, I actually need to use a Microsoft Account.

(As it happens, my email address is associated with both an organizational account, and also a Microsoft Account. This may not be helping.)

I could create a completely separate organizational account in an Azure Active Directory, make that a co-admin, and log in with that, but it seems like this shouldn't be necessary.

Is there some way to force it to offer me both options?

Comment: My email address is associated with both too, and I do get the option of which account to use. I've had this before with Visual Studio though - have you tried clearing your cookies?

Comment: Clearing cookies doesn't seem to help, sadly.

Comment: It's worth trying the 0.8.7 version released a couple days ago, although I don't see anything in the change log for `Add-AzureAccount`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the new version, but sadly, no change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @outlook.com instead of the organizational address and you will be directed to the Microsoft Account login.

Comment: Ah, very clever! (In case anyone else is reading this answer and wondering how it works, be aware that the universal Microsoft web login UI looks at what you've typed into the email address box when you move the focus to the password box, and in cases where it can work out that a domain is *definitely* a particular kind of account it promptly navigates to a different page specific to that kind of login. And since all outlook.com addresses are Microsoft Accounts, typing just x@outlook.com and hitting Tab will trigger just such a navigation.) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this problem through trial-and-error.  As Paul points out in his post, you can load your subscription info into PowerShell using the following sequence:

**1. Get-AzurePublishSettingsFile**

This will open a browser to a special page that lets you download your profile settings file.

*Note: If you have multiple subscriptions, you must use the dropdown to select the one that contains the Azure components you want to manage. For instance, I have a BizSpark subscription that I use for my own company, and a separate MSDN subscription that my clients use (adding me as an administrator).  Both subscriptions show up on my management portal page, so I needed to download 2 separate publishsettings files.*

**2. Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile  my-subscription.publishsettings**

In my case, I renamed the settings files to "BizSpark.publishsettings" and "MSDN.publishsettings", so I ran this command twice.

**3. Get-AzureSubscription**

This will list all of the subscriptions that have been imported into PowerShell, showing the subscription name and the other properties.

**4. Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "my-subscription"**

You can now use the subscription name to select the subscription you want to use.  This allows you to switch back and forth between subscriptions and work with the Azure components you need to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Azure can be signed up with either Microsoft Account or Organizational Account. Add-AzureAccount will display a message like "Sign in with your organizational account" in the browser window, but actually if you input your Microsoft Account email address into the box and move focus out, the page will redirect to Microsoft Account sign page automatically, and then you can sign in.

Sometimes you may meet some error like "The cache contains multiple tokens satisfying the requirements". You can try to clean all the existing Azure Accounts firstly and then try to sign in again.

To clean up, run Get-AzureAccount | Remove-AzureAccount.

Comment: That doesn't work. If I try to sign in with my Microsoft Account it just complains with "We don't recognize this user ID or password". I'm fairly sure the reason for this is that, as I said in my question, the email address I'm using is both a Microsoft Account AND an Organizational Account. If that weren't the case, then I can see it would go "oh, that's not an org account, let's see if it's a Microsoft account". But since mine is both, it just concludes instead that I've mistyped the password for my org account...

Comment: Same here. We have registered+running Azure services on Microsoft account, but cannot access them via Powershell, because only organizational account is allowed. As most of advanced capabilities of Azure is powershell only, this ex-post limitation makes our Azure useless for now

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. Using `Add-AzureAccount` with my Microsoft Account result in adding my organizational account.

For example I run `Add-AzureAccount`, in the form I type `davideicardi@hotmail.com` (my Microsoft account) but the resulted account is `davide.icardi@mycompany.com` (my organizational account).

I solved by deleting all the Azure account registered on Power Shell (also the one not related to my account, using `Remove-AzureAccount`), then I have deleted IE cookies (not sure it this is important...), closed the powershell console and executing again `Add-AzureAccount`.

I suspect that there is a bug somewhere...